# Is there an easy way in ES6 to reduce an interator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a Map which is filled with entries and I would like to sum the values.
The problem is: reduce() only seems to work for arrays, while map.values() returns an iterator.

Is there some easy way to do this or is some external library required?

Comment: could you provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

There don't yet exist utility methods on the iterator interface, but you can trivially fold using a `for of` loop:

```
let sum = 0;
for (const value of myMap.values())
    sum += value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var sum = 0;
myMap.forEach((value, key)=> sum+=value);
```